# What function can be used to sort a Vector?

Tags: java, vector, sorting

I cant find any sorting function in the java API for vectors.
`Collections.sort` is only for `List<T>` and not for `Vector<T>`.

I don't want to write my own sorting function because I think java should implement this.

I'm looking for something like:

```
class ClassName implements Comparator<ClassName> ..
ClassName cn = ..;
sort(cn);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As per the [API docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), `Vector` just implements `List`, so I don't forsee problems. Maybe your confusion was caused because you declared `Vector` according the old Java 1.0 style:

```
Vector vector = new Vector();
```

instead of the declaring it aginst the interface (which is considered good practice):

```
List list = new Vector();
```

You can thus just make use of [`Collections#sort()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) to sort a collection, [`Comparable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to define the default ordering behaviour and/or [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to define an external controllable ordering behaviour.

Here's a [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) about ordering objects.

Here's another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts/1814112#1814112) with complete code examples.

That said, why are you still sticking to the *legacy* `Vector` class? If you can, just replace by the improved [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which was been designed as replacement of `Vector` more than a decade ago.

Answer (score 15):

Vector implements List, so Collections.sort would work.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Java API Specification for the [`Vector`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class, it implements the [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface which is needed to use the [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) method.

Also, as a note, for most uses the `Vector` class could be replaced by using one of the `List` implementations in the Java Collections Framework, such as [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). The `Vector` class is synchronized, so unless there is a real need for synchronized access one should use one of the other `List` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Vector is a List

Answer (score 1):

Collections.sort(nameOfTheVectorToBeSorted); try this on your vector, that will get sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add `implements Comparable<>` in your class:

```
public class XXXX 
    implements Comparable<XXXX> {

}
```

And to redefine `compareTo()` in your class of the object type stored in your vector.

I got this problem as well, Eclipse IDE was telling me that `Collection.sort()` was for `List<T>` only. Couldn't make it work until I did what I just said.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort(vector_name)`

It'll sort the vector in place, so you don't need to assign the result of the above command back to the vector.

This works because Vectors are implementations of Lists.