# Sorting Anagrams

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write an algorithm that sort out anagrams from the given set of words. So far I got this

```
package Tutorial5;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 


public class Anagrams {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/Tutorial5/words"); //locate and open the txt.file

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis); //get the words from the txt.file

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));

            String SLine;


            while ((SLine = br.readLine()) != null) //read the txt.file line by line
            {
                System.out.println(SLine); //print out the words
        }

        dis.close(); //close the DataInputStream

    }
        catch (Exception e) //see if there is any exception to catch
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

}
}
```

Can anyone please help me out? I'm struggling with the sorting part. I don't know how to use this code I got and convert it into string and have it sort into anagrams.

Comment: What exactly does your input contain? Just one word per line or already some anagrams that you just have to sort. Or do you have to build anagrams out of the input words? You have to be more precise to get constructive answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>();
while ((SLine = br.readLine()) != null) //read the txt.file line by line
{
    strings.add(SLine);
    System.out.println(SLine); //print out the words
}
```

Now you have the String in a Vector which you can use to sort them.
Creat your sort algorithm as seperate function:

```
void sortStrings(Vector<String> strings) {
// ...
}
```

How to do the acutal sorting you can find out yourself, there is a lot of stuff avalible: [What function can be used to sort a Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072032/sorting-vector-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Finding out if two words are anagrams are not really that complicated if you think of it this way: as long as both strings have equal length and same letters, they are anagrams.

So, you need to write a method that takes in two strings, sort these strings and check them if they have the same value on the same index. In code it would be something simular to this:

```
  public boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
     if (str1.length() != str2.length()) 
         return false; // can't be an anagram since not equal length
     for (int i = i<str1.length;i++) { // loop thru the string
        if (str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)) // is the char at index i in str1 not equal to char at the same index in str2?
            return false;
         }
      return true;
```

Please notice, that for this method to work, the strings needs to be sorted and should not contain spaces etc. Since this is homework i'll leave that work for you to make :)

Answer (score 0):

How about making all those string into Array list than sort the array list.
while you print add to the array list then sort it.. simple coding..