# Alphabetical Vector Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, vector

I'm helping a friend with a project and we can't seem to find a reason for this sorting method not to work. I have suspicions on what the problem is but I have no idea on how to solve it or replace it with an alternative.

The program tracks data from donations, and we are trying to implement a feature to alphabetize the names of donors to no avail.

Our method for sorting through the vector and alphabetizing:

```
//from other classes:    
Vector <Donor> infoVector  = new Vector <Donor>();
String FName;

Donor tempDonor = new Donor ();

int drawer = 0; 

for (int x = 0; x<infoVector.size(); x++)    
{
    for (int y = x+1; y<infoVector.size(); y++)
    {
        drawer = y;
    }
    if(infoVector.elementAt(x).getFName().compareTo(infoVector.elementAt(drawer).getFName()) < 0)
    {
        tempDonor  = infoVector.elementAt(x);
        infoVector.setElementAt(infoVector.elementAt(drawer), x);
        infoVector.setElementAt(tempDonor, drawer);
    }
}
```

This doesn't sort the donor names when we output them; I think it has to do with comparing the names using "compareTo" but  I don't have a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are library methods that will do the sorting for you. Take a look at [`Collections.sort(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) or [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

The reason your code doesn't work, I believe, is because of the braces for your inner `for` loop. Right now all the inner loop does is assign `infoVector.size() - 1` to `drawer`, as according to your braces you don't do anything with `drawer` in the meantime. I suspect what you want to do is put the `if` block inside the inner loop.

Some more nitpicky things: `drawer` isn't strictly necessary; in your original code you can simply substitute `infoVector.size() - 1` instead (or a variable that contains that value). Also, the sorting method isn't the most efficient sort you could use, although if `infoVector` is short enough and this method isn't called too frequently it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
for (int y = x+1; y<infoVector.size(); y++)
{
    drawer = y;
}
```

is going to fully iterate through the vector and so `y` will always be `infoVector.size() - 1`

Even though you put `tempDonor` at the end, the next iteration, you are moving it back.

Rather than trying to invent the wheel, use Collections.sort.

See [What function can be used to sort a Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072032/what-function-can-be-used-to-sort-a-vector)
and 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)

Comment: What would you suggest to fix that?