# How to make compareTo sort a list alphabetically?

Tags: java

How do I change my code so that it lists the elements in alphabetical order from a to z.  Right now it's ordering from z to a.  I can't figure it out and am stuck :-/

```
    String sName1 = ((Address)o).getSurname().toLowerCase();
    String sName2 = (this.surname).toLowerCase();
    int result = (sName1).compareTo(sName2);

    return result;
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Just swap the objects you're comparing.

```
int result = (sName2).compareTo(sName1);
```

Usually, for ascending sorting you'd like the lefthand side be part of *this* object and the righthand side be part of the *other* object. For descending sorting you just swap the both sides (which you thus initially did).

To make your code more intuitive, I'd however rather swap the assignments of `sName1` and `sName2`:

```
String sName1 = (this.surname).toLowerCase();
String sName2 = ((Address)o).getSurname().toLowerCase();
int result = (sName1).compareTo(sName2);
```

*And get rid of the hungarian notation and unnecessary parentheses as well*. The following sums it:

```
public class Address implements Comparable<Address> {
    private String surname;
    // ...

    public int compareTo(Address other) {
        return this.surname.toLowerCase().compareTo(other.surname.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

You may want to add nullchecks if you can't guarantee that surname is never `null`.

**See also:**

- [Object Ordering tutorial at Sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)
- [Different ways to sort a list of Javabeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts/1814112#1814112)

Comment: And get rid of the unneeded parentheses.

Comment: That can be further simplified:

    public int compareTo(Address other) {
        return this.surname.compareToIgnoreCase(other.surname);
    }

Comment: Also get rid of the unnecessary "this" before variables. </nitpick>