# Adding elements to array in alphebetical order

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program which adds telephone entries into a staff phone directory, I want to add the elements to the array in alphabetical order (using surnames) rather than adding the elements then calling Arrays.sort every time a new entry is added, as that would be less efficient. Here is some code I have so far, I'm not sure how to compare each element in the array with the following one and so forth.

```
public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory {

Entry [] directory = new Entry [50];

@Override
public void addEntry(String initials, String surname, int extension) {

     //Entries are added here in alphabetical order

}
```

Here is my Entry class -

```
public class Entry  {

private String initals,surname;
private int extention;

public Entry(String initals, String surname, int extention){
    this.initals = initals;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.extention = extention;
}

public String getInitals(){

    return initals; 
}
public String getSurname(){

    return surname;
}
public int getExtention(){

    return extention;
}

}
```

Any suggestions, do I override compareTo?  Thanks

edit - should have noted I have been asked to use an array. Sorry for the confusion.

Edit 2: updated my addEntry method and overriden compareTo in Entry -

```
public void addEntry(String initials, String surname, int extension) {

    for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
        if (directory[i] != null) {
            int y = directory[i].getSurname().compareTo(surname);
            if (y == 1) {
                int position = i;
                break;
            }
        } else if (directory[i] == null) {
            int position = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And my compareTo method -

```
public int compareTo(Entry other) {     
    return this.surname.compareTo(other.getSurname());
}
```

I'm not sure how to shift the elements in the array to the right after I have found the correct position? Thank you for all of you help.

Comment: Do you **have** to use an array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933024/how-to-make-compareto-sort-a-list-alphabetically
Try to read this

Comment: Arrays.sort() is not particularly innefficient for what you are doing... The time that you will take will be used shifting the remainder of the array.

Comment: Why not use a `TreeSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `Entry` comparable and implement the `compareTo` in it. But you don't really have to  in this case because `String` is already comparable.

Since this is a homework, I think it will be best to just give you some suggestions on how to proceed, instead of handing you the code -

In your method you do not need to sort the array, you just need to insert it at the correct location in the array.

1. loop through the array starting at the first index
2. as you pass through each element in the array, you will have to check following two conditions

   1. is the element null
   2. is the `surname` of current element greater than `surname`-argument to the method
3. as soon as you find the element that satisfies any of the above conditions, record the index and break the loop
4. then, starting at that index shift the rest of elements to the right
5. and finally create a new instance of `Entry` for the provided arguments and set it at that index

Note: This doesn't take care of the situation where you are out of the space in the array.

---

Update:

I think you mixed up my answer and @David Wallace's answer. It wasn't my suggestion to implement `compareTo`. Also, it's great that you at least gave it a try and came back.

```
int position = -1; //declare the position outside (if declared inside, it's not visible outside the loop)
for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
     // position = i; just assign value of i inside the loop
}

//use the position after the loop
int j = position; // start at position
Entry temp = null; // temp will temporarily hold the entry at the next index
while(true) { 
    temp = directory[j + 1]; // since we need move entry at j to j+1, first we need save the entry at j+1
    directory[j + 1] = directory[j]; // entry at j to j+1
    if(temp == null) { // if the next entry is null, don't really need to move no more, so break
        break;
    }
}
// finally place new entry at index position
directory[position] = //the new Entry
```

Comment: How would I go about shifting the elements right? I've updated my code above. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have to use an array then your using the wrong data structure.

No matter what path you need to implement Comparable:

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{

..

@Override
public int compareTo(Entry other) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.surname.compareTo(other.getSurname());
}
..
```

Consider using a SortedSet:

```
   Set<Entry> map = new TreeSet<Entry>();

   map.add(new Entry("JEH", "Hamlet", 123));
   map.add(new Entry("AAC", "Adams", 123));
   map.add(new Entry("FAM", "Monti", 321));
```

That will print in the desired order.  If you must use an Array then you need to sort it upon insert.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Entry` implement `Comparable<Entry>` and write the appropriate `compareTo` method in your `Entry` class.  Then, in your `insert` method, you want to

- Use `Arrays.binarySearch` to find the right place in the array to insert your the entry.
- Use `System.arraycopy` to shift everything in the array that's after the appropriate location one place to the right.
- Set the appropriate entry.

You'll want to check out the Javadoc for `Arrays.binarySearch` and `System.arraycopy`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never use arrays unless you absolutely *have* to. Use Collecctions instead - they are far easier to deal with and have support for lots of operations you commonly want to perform on groups of things.

In your case, a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) would be a good choice. If you want to sort the entries by surname only in this usage (and not generally), you can pass a customer `Comparator` to the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29):

```
Set<Entry> directory = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Entry>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2) {
        return o1.getSurname().compareTo(o2.getSurname());
    }
});
```

If your *always* want to sort `Entry` objects using surname, have your `Entry` class implement `Comparable<Entry>` and move the code into the `compareTo()` method of the `Entry` class.