# How to define multiple equals() function for a class

Tags: java

I want to override "public boolean equals(Object obj)" function, for name and age, in my class named MyObject whose structure is given below

```
public class MyObject{
       private String name;
       private int age;
}
```

How can i ?

@balusC :

What about this ?

```
vo  = new MyObject() {
                    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                        return ((MyObject)obj).name().equals(this.getName());

                    }


vo  = new MyObject() {
                    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                        return ((MyObject)obj).age() == (this.getAge());
```

Comment: btw: I think the intent of your question is pretty obvious despite what people said

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but if the sole purpose is to have different sorting algorithms depending on what property you'd like to use, then rather use a [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public static Comparator COMPARE_BY_NAME = new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person one, Person other) {
            return one.name.compareTo(other.name);
        }
    }

    public static Comparator COMPARE_BY_AGE = new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person one, Person other) {
            return one.age > other.age ? 1
                 : one.age < other.age ? -1
                 : 0; // Maybe compare by name here? I.e. if same age, then order by name instead.
        }
    }

    // Add/generate getters/setters/equals()/hashCode()/toString()
}
```

which you can use as follows:

```
List<Person> persons = createItSomehow();

Collections.sort(persons, Person.COMPARE_BY_NAME);
System.out.println(persons); // Ordered by name.

Collections.sort(persons, Person.COMPARE_BY_AGE);
System.out.println(persons); // Ordered by age.
```

As to the actual `equals()` implementation, I'd rather let it return true when the both `Person` objects are techically or naturally identical. You can use either a DB-generated PK for this to compare on technical identity:

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return (object instanceof Person) && (id != null) 
             ? id.equals(((Person) object).id) 
             : (object == this);
    }
}
```

or just compare every property to compare on natural identity:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // Basic checks.
        if (object == this) return true;
        if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;

        // Property checks.
        Person other = (Person) object;
        if (name == null ? other.name != null : !name.equals(other.name)) return false;
        if (age != other.age) return false;

        // All passed.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to override `hashCode()` as well when you override `equals()`.

#### See also:

- [Object ordering](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)
- [Sorting an ArrayList of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts)
- [Overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you're aiming at with this. The general expectation of equals() is that it returns `false` for `null` and objects of other classes and performs value equality on the relevant fields of the class in question.

While you can certainly handle `String` and `Integer` in the following way:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o == null) return false;
  if (o instanceof String) return name.equals(o);
  if (o instanceof Integer) return ((Integer)o) == age;
  ...
}
```

this breaks the contract for `equals` so you *can't* do it (except not without things going wrong in very weird ways).

`equals` is an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), so it has to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive. The symmetric part here is key, since if `a.equals(b)` then `b.equals(a)`. Both `String` and `Integer` won't do that for you.

If you want just helper functions that check whether the name or the age is equals to a given name/age, then you can do that without using `equals()`:

```
public boolean equalsName(String name) { return name.equals(this.name); }
public boolean equalsAge(int age) { return age == this.age; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just keep it short and simple (aka **KISS** principle): write **setters** and **getters**. Something like in the following example:

```
public class Person {  
  private String name;  
  private int age;  

public String getName() {  
  return name;  
}

public int getAge() {  
  return age;  
}
```

And then in the method you need to do the check you can write:

```
Person person = new Person();
if(person.getName().equals("Something")) doThis();
if(person.getAge() == 1337) doThat();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do want to override equals, it should look something like this:

```
static private <T> boolean checkEquals(T t1, T t2)
{
   return (t1 == null) ? (t2 == null) : t1.equals(t2);
}
@Override public boolean equals (Object o)
{
   if (o instanceof MyObject)
   {
     MyObject obj = (MyObject)o;
     return checkEquals(this.name, obj.getName()) 
         && this.age == o.getAge();
   }
   else
     return false;
}

@Override public int hashCode() 
{
   // implement hashCode
}
```

You need to override *both* hashCode() and equals() or neither. [And you also should make sure your class is `final`, otherwise there are potential pitfalls with equals](http://www.drdobbs.com/184405053).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "multiple equals()". If you want compare both your fields, you just need to override the equals method like this,

```
public boolean equals( Object o )
{
    if ( o != null && o instanceof MyObject )
    {
        MyObject m = (MyObject) o;
        if (this.name == null)
            return false;
        return this.name.eqauls(m.name) && this.age == m.age;
    }
    return false;
}

/// Compute a hash code for the pair.
public int hashCode()
{
    int code = name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode();
    return code ^ age;
}
```

It's a good practice to change hashCode whenever you change equals so HashMap works efficiently with your object.

Comment: check o != null is redundant - null instanceof MyObject will be false

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyObject { 
    private String name; 
    private int age; 

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof MyObject){
            MyObject otherObject = (MyObject)o;
            if(name == null){
                return otherObject.name == null && otherObject.age == age;
            } else {
                return name.equals(otherObject.name) && otherObject.age == age;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // When we overriding equals it is a good practice to override hashCode
    // for consistecy
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        int nameCode = (name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode();
        // See Item 9 in book Effective Java 2nd Edition
        return 31 * nameCode + age;
    }

}
```