# Java Comparator - Two level comparison on object

Tags: java

I am using java Comparator which need sorting based on below conditions -

> Object1 -  name subName
>
> Object2 - name subName

Compare Object1 & Object2 based on below condition-

> condition 1: if name != subName -- push it up while sorting
>
> condition 2: if name == subName -- push it down while sorting

Can anyone help, how to implement this?

Comment: You can probably just use that exact pseudo-code to accomplish your goal...

Comment: You should read that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117044/how-to-use-java-comparator-properly

Answer (score -1):

Comparator is a interface. 
So under your situation, Object1 and Object2 should be the instance from the same Object ,assume NameObject.
you can add a Comparator interface on the NameObject. and create a new "compare" method .
After the you can use sort.

```
public class NameObject implements Comparator{
 private String name;
 private String subName;
 //getter and setter
 compare(NameObject o1, NameObject o2){
  //do some thing you want.
 }
}
```

That also OK if you want to implement the "Comparator" independently.

Comment: `Comparator` is not intended for this purpose.. You should use `Comparable` instead here.

Comment: if(sc1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(sc1.getSubName()) && !sc2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(sc2.getSubName())){
 return 1;
}
if(sc2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(sc2.getSubName()) && !sc1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(sc1.getSubName())){
 return -1;
}

then I have other condition which checks another field on sc1 & sc2 

int diff = sc2.getTotalVal().compareTo(sc1.getTotalVal());
 if(difference == 0){
  return sc2.userId().compareTo(sc1.userId());
 }
 else{
  return difference;
 }
 
 Each time I run this code, i get different sorting results, what is wrong here?

Comment: compareTo is Comparable interface.  I think you have some confusion about how to sort the list by using Comparable or Comparator. check the link below :http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/