# How to check if a date in a list is most current

Tags: java, datetime, date

I have a `List` of news feed with **date** attached, I want to walkthrough the list to determine which of the news feed's date is most current - and so I can arrange the news in the order of most current.

Any I deas how to achieve this?

Comment: how is the date being stored?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts

Comment: How are the dates represented in the feed?

Comment: `@Brett Walker` Date is attached to the feed heading as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the list using a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) based on the date of the item, then pick the first item using [list.get(0)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29).

Here's an compilable and runnable implementation:

```
static class NewsFeed {
    String news;
    Date date;

    private NewsFeed(String news, Date date) {
        this.news = news;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getNews() {
        return news;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<NewsFeed> list = new ArrayList<NewsFeed>();

    list.add(new NewsFeed("A", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000)));
    list.add(new NewsFeed("B", new Date())); // This one is the "latest"
    list.add(new NewsFeed("C", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 2000)));

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<NewsFeed>() {
        public int compare(NewsFeed arg0, NewsFeed arg1) {
            // Compare in reverse order ie biggest first
            return arg1.getDate().compareTo(arg0.getDate()); 
        }
    });
    NewsFeed latestNewsFeed = list.get(0);
    System.out.println(latestNewsFeed.getNews()); // Prints "B", as expected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way would be to either sort the List e.g. sort in descending order using Collections.sort() with a custom comparator. Or use PriorityQueue and extract out the next new time each time (useful if say you only want the 10 most recent)

Answer (score 0):

You can `Collections.sort` your list of `Feed` classes passing a `Comparator` comparing to the dates that I am guessing are fields on your `Feed` class

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for the objects contained in your `List` and then call the [Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method with this `List` to sort and the created `Comparator` as parameters.