# Collection.sort/reverse/reverOrder

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections

I have an Arraylist of songs which store title, artist and time
I have all my code written up and everything. I just wanted to know more about Collection.sort and Collection.reverse and Collection.reverseOrder. I have a file that has all the songs and everything. 
I want to sort the songs according to descending order according to time.

When I try this I either get an error or it doesnt sort properly. can anyone suggest how I 
cant use Collection.sort and use the comparator

```
Comparator<Song> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
Collections.reverse(listOfSongs);
```

My compare method is as follows:

```
public int compare(Song mySong1,Song mySong2 ){
        if (mySong1.getLength() > mySong2.getLength()){
            return -1; 
        }
        if(mySong1.getLength() < mySong2.getLength()){
            return 1;
        }
        if(mySong1.getLength() == mySong2.getLength())
        {
            if(mySong1.getTitle().compareTo(mySong2.getTitle()) > 0){
                return -1;
            }
            if(mySong1.getTitle().compareTo(mySong2.getTitle())  < 0 ){
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                if(mySong1.getComposer().compareTo(mySong2.getComposer())  >0){
                    return -1;
                }
                if(mySong1.getComposer().compareTo(mySong2.getComposer())  <0) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: What type of objects are stored in your ArrayList?

Comment: Man, did you make another account? This question came up for 5 times in the last 24h.

Comment: they are Song objects in the ArrayList

Comment: There are Song objects in the ArrayList.

Comment: I have used this class  Song implements Comparator<Song>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219597/sorting-songs-in-java,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200729/which-algorithms-are-good-for-sorting-songs

Answer (score 9):

`Collections.reverse` doesn't sort. It just reverse the order of the elements of the list. So if the list contains `T, F, Z`, it will contain `Z, F, T`.

Your code snipper initialize a comparator, but doesn't do anything with it. And this comparator only works, as [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29) says, if the elements of the collection implement the `Comparable` interface.

You should either make the `Song` class implement the `Comparable` interface (look at its javadoc to know what this interface must do), or you must use a specific `Comparator` implementation. Whatever the chosen solution is, you'll have to implement some code to tell `Collections.sort` how the songs compare with each other. Is a song before another one when its title comes before the other song's title? Or is it when its duration is shorter than the other one?

See [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts)

Comment: Party Rock Anthem&Lmfao&327747 
Last Friday Night&Katy Perry&370907 
Tonight, Tonight&Hot Chelle Rae&355536 
How To Love&Lil Wayne&279222 
Pumped Up Kicks&Foster The People&355968 
Super Bass&Nicki Minaj&223744 
I Wanna Go&Britney Spears&267875 
Give Me Everything&Pitbull&304190 
Rolling In The Deep&Adele&315421 
Good Life&OneRepublic&237007 

Our job is to extract the title and artist and the time from this. I am using a separator to get the title, artist and time and I am storing this in an String array which has Title[] Artist[] and Time[], the time is converted to int after

Comment: the Song class does implement Comparable<Song>

Comment: If Song is comparable, use Collections.sort(list) to sort the list. Use Collection.sort(Collections.reverseOrder()) to sort the list in descending order. This is obvious if you read the javadoc.