# Sorting map according to user defined criteria?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator, comparable

I have a map in which I want some values to be come on top.

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
hm.put("Phone Number","998291829");
hm.put("Address","12 A Street");
hm.put("Name","Robert Singh");
hm.put("Email","robert@gmail.com");
-
-
```

I want Name and email as first and second entry,How can I do this.

Comment: Do you want the items to be sorted in the way they are inserted?

Comment: I understand he wants them in a specific order.

Comment: No Actually values and keys are coming from caouchdb, and i have to use this map to show on u.i. Where key is the label and value is the value next to label.

Comment: @vikasTheJavaDeveloper then you should follow the advice from Peter Lawrey: create a class that will have the attributes "name", "email", and others, then you fill it with the data and you can display it easily in your UI.

Comment: @Dan something I've learned here on SO is that OP won't (always) write the real problem, instead the problem with the solution he/she tries to apply :).

Comment: This is not 'sorting' but 'sequencing'.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap is not a sorted or sortable collection.

What you can do is use TreeMap with your own Comparator.

However, I suspect you would be better off using a real class instead of an ad-hoc Map.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest treemap for performance reason. For this case a linkedhashmap with custom compartor with be ok.

Comment: LinkedHashMap doesn't take a custom comparator, or a custom hash function either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `HashMap`, you should use a `LinkedHashMap` because it preserves the order you add the elements. You would have to add the elements in the order you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tree map. The constructor accepts a comparator.

You can pass your own implementation of the comparator where in you can implement the logic of ordering the data in your map.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a bean e.g. Contact or Person and then write comparator for this.

So once you are done creating bean and comparator for it. Then

Populate the list/collection of bean

and the finally do

Collection.sort(yourlist,sortByNameComparator);

Collection.sort(yourlist,sortByemailComparator);

Where sortByNameComparator and sortByemailComparator are the comparators you created.

Take a look at this. it will definitely solve your problem.

[Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name?lq=1)

The above has example of creating comparators.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your usage, you might want to use a `List<Pair>`, where Pair is something like

```
public class Pair<J,K> {
    private J key;
    private K value;

    public Pair(J key, K value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public J getKey() {return key;}
    public K getValue() {return value;}
}
```

Comment: How's this supposed to help OP in the current problem? Using this list will become useless if someone needs to use a fast and good `get` method.