# Create a list / arraylist of objects and sort the list (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name)

I have a student object and then I create ArrayList and add student to the list.

```
ArrayList<Student_Object> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, I want to sort the list by studentId fleid. How can I do it?

Is there a better solution? Thanks

---

So I have this method in the Student _Object class

Class is:

```
class Student_Object implements Comparator<Student_Object>
```

The method is:

```
public int compare(Student_Object student1, Student_Object student2){
    String student1TUID = student1.getTUID();        
    String student2TUID = student2.getTUID();

return student1TUID.compareTo(student2TUID);   


}
```

From where do I run the statment?

```
Collections.sort(studentsList);
```

If I run it from my main class I get error in netbeans:

```
no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<Student_Object>)
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>,Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
        inferred: Student_Object
        bound(s): Comparable<? super Student_Object>)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>,Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Comparable<? super T#2> declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>)
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

---

Got it to work. I used **Collections.sort(studentsList, new Student_Object());**

Thanks everyone

Comment: Student_Object is redundant, just use Student

Comment: @RohitJain in reality it should be combined and a new question of the form "Sort list based on arbitrary field", however those combinations seem to get knocked down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be:

Write a `comparator` and override `compare` method. Then use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) by passing comparator.

Example:

```
class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    public int compare(Student stud1, Student stud2){

        int stu1ID = stud1.getId();       
        int stu2ID = stud2.getId();

        if(stu1ID > stu2ID)
            return 1;
        else if(stu1ID < st21ID )
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;    
    }

}
```

Another flavor may be:

```
 class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

        public int compare(Student stud1, Student stud2){

            int stu1ID = stud1.getId();       
            int stu2ID = stud2.getId();

           return stud1ID-stu2ID;
        }

    }
```

This [tutorial](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html) may help you.

Comment: Better implement a generic Comparator. No typecast needed. And why not just do: - `return stuID1 - stud2ID;`??

Comment: @RohitJain: The tutorial I have added as reference not using generics, I thought that may confuse OP. Thanks for edit.

Comment: @RohitJain: I guess stud1-stud2 is not guaranteed to return either 1, -1, 0. Sometimes it could be higher vlaue, isn't it?

Comment: You're welcome. You can also consider returning simply the difference, rather than that if-else block. that will do the job. :)

Comment: Yeah but does it matter? `sort` method just care about, positive or negative value, or 0 for equal.

Comment: @RohitJain: You are correct, it just cares about negative (or) positive (or) 0. Updated answer.

Comment: +1 for posting both the flavours. I like more number of flavours :)

Comment: @Nambari Thanks, how to I call the sort?  **Collection.sort(studentsList, new StudentComparator());** Like this?

Comment: Yes, with small correction, it should be Collections NOT Collection. make sure 's'

Comment: I'm getting: **no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<Student_Object>)**

Comment: @Mike: Please update question with latest code.

Comment: @Mike: Can you change ArrayList<Student_Object> studentsList = new ArrayList<>(); to ArrayList<Student_Object> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student_Object>(); ? and see

Comment: @Nambari I got it to works thanks. I used **Collections.sort(studentsList, new Student_Object());**

Comment: @Mike: Glad it helped you.Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 4):

To do sorting you need to implement the `Comparable` interface.  I would also highly recommend implementing equals and hashCode while you are in there.  Example:

```
public class Student implements Comparable  
{  
    private String name;  
    private int id;  
    ...

    public int compareTo(Student otherStudent)  
    {  
       if(this.id < otherStudent.id)  
       {  
          return -1;
       }  
       else if(this.id > otherStudent.id)  
       {  
           return 1;
       }  
        else{
           return 0;  
        }  

    }  
}
```

Comment: `public int compareTo(Student otherStudent) { return this.id - otherStudent.id; }` will do the job, too ;)

Comment: @jlordo indeed it will,not sure which is faster though, doing a calculation or doing a logical compare.

Comment: please change your return type to `int`

Comment: @jlordo to quick on the typing =p

Comment: Performance is an interesting point, does anyone know how the resulting bytecode looks?