# Insert objects in LinkedList based on object's calendar object

Tags: java, date, linked-list

I'm making a list of transactions, each transaction have a set of data fields including a calendar object. I would like to insert these transaction objects to a LinkedList based on the date in the transactions calendar object. In other words, sorted by date.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please clarify. What does "based on the date"? Do you mean that you want the list sorted by date?

Comment: Yes, I wan't the sorted by date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name) and of many other questions explaining how to sort a list

Comment: put them into a LinkedList and sort using comparator taking two transaction object and comparing their calendar fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give it to you:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    public int compareTo(MyClass a, MyClass b) {
        return a.getDate().compareTo(b.getDate());
    }
}
```