# How does implementing an interface provide additional functionality?

Tags: java

I understand that an interface is a contract for classes and that if a class implements an interface, then all methods in the interface must be in the class.

Here is an example involving interfaces from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name?lq=1) that confuses me:

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

    private String name;

    public int compareTo(Contact other) {
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
}
```

You can then obviously create an `ArrayList` and sort it by name.

```
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Collections.sort(contacts);
```

But if `Contract` does not implement `Comparable` like so:

```
public class Contact {

    private String name;

    public int compareTo(Contact other) {
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
}
```

Calling `Collections.sort` will give a compile time error even though the `compareTo` method still exists.

Clearly there can be additional functionality provided by implementing interfaces. What is the purpose of interfaces other than for enforcing structure?

Comment: No, "enforcing structure" is entirely the purpose of interfaces.  (This changes a little in Java 8, though...)

Comment: Interfaces are excellent, very flexible design tool. It's about typing. Collections.sort is declared like sort(Collection<? extends Comparable>) so again typing issue. I'd recommend you to take a look at Java 8 feature: some methods in Java 8 would work like Collections.sort(collection, Contract::compareTo)

Comment: @krems `sort(Collection<? extends Comparable>)` is patently wrong, it allows classes to be passed that don't `extends Comparable` of _themselves_. Please check your facts before posting.

Comment: @Boris the Spider I didn't say that's exactly that way, just tried to make the stuff a bit easier to understand. BTW sort function can't have a Collection as an argument, cause not every collection is ordered, in fact Collections.sort takes List, the actual signature is given in answers below and is as follows: 
`<T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`
So I didn't really want to duplicate complicated and already written stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if `Contact implements Comparable<Contact>` then `Contact` *is a* `Comparable<Contact>`.

Lets take a look at the source code, deep down in `ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending()` there is the line:

```
if (((Comparable) a[runHi++]).compareTo(a[lo]) < 0)
```

The pertinent bit is `((Comparable) a[runHi++])` - `a[runHi++]` is **cast** to a `Comparable` and then the `compareTo` is called on that *as a* `Comparable`.

So if `Contact implements Comparable<Contact>` I can do this:

```
final Comparable<Contact> contact = new Contact();
```

If it does not, then I obviously cannot assign the instance to a `Comparable` type and therefore I have no idea (without resorting to reflection) what methods `Contact` has.

By implementing `Comparable` I am telling the compiler that this class *is a* `Comparable` and therefore can be treated as one where required. Having to implement the methods is merely a side effect of that.

As to why it's a **compile time** rather than **run time** error, you only need to look at the declaration of the method `Collections.sort` to find out:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

So this method is a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) and it's signature asks for a `List<T>` where `T extends Comparable<? super T>`. This is a little tricky to lets break it down.

We need `T` to `extends Comparable<? super T>`. So `T` needs to `implements Comparable<? super T>` or some subclass of `Comparable`. `? super T` means that it can be `Comparable` on the type `T` or any *supertype* - i.e. if your `compareTo` can sort `Object` then it can also sort `T` (by the Liskov substitution principle).

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is the technical one, but from a design point of view they create a layer of abstraction between the layers of program. This is important when designing a complex system because it reduces dependencies between classes and allows for greater maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers gave more common usages of interfaces. There are 2 more I am thinking about :

- simple marker. `Serializable` contains no method, nor constants, but simply declare that an instance of the class can be successfully serialized to a stream and de-serialized back.
- JDK proxying. A `Proxy` can only proxies interfaces. So to proxy a class, you must first *export* its public methods to one or more interfaces. It is commonly used in Spring framework AOP.

Comment: It's not `@Serializable` because that would be an annotation. In fact the usage of `Serializable` is one of the worst design decisions in the JDK and should not be held up as a example to beginners. Marker interfaces should not be used as annotations exist. Your second example is a massive over-simplification of what is a very complex runtime process.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: thank for noticing the extraneous `@`. I agree that it is a bad design, but it is in the JDK and it took me quite a long time to understand that interfaces could be used as simple markers (I learnt Java by myself ...). And I also admit that proxying is much more complex than what I wrote. I only wanted to insist on the fact that layer separation with interfaces was required to use Spring AOP. But your answer is much better than mine :-)