# Add two sections in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application i am using recyclerview to display all contact list.
I want two section in recyclerview.

Like one section is my application contact list and second section is my phone contact list.

**Like this**

[image]

Is there any method to do it?

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Can you please show your efforts or elaborate more

Comment: see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: Have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34464367/2739684

Comment: Checkout for sticky section : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62865328/14784590

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you already have a `RecyclerView`, an easy way to implement the sections is using Gabriele Mariotti's [SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058).

I paste you his example:

```
//Your RecyclerView
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

//Your RecyclerView.Adapter
mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,sCheeseStrings);


//This is the code to provide a sectioned list
List<SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section> sections =
        new ArrayList<SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section>();

//Sections
sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(0,"Section 1"));
sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(5,"Section 2"));
sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(12,"Section 3"));
sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(14,"Section 4"));
sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(20,"Section 5"));

//Add your adapter to the sectionAdapter
SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[] dummy = new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[sections.size()];
SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter mSectionedAdapter = new
          SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(this,R.layout.section,R.id.section_text,mAdapter);
mSectionedAdapter.setSections(sections.toArray(dummy));

//Apply this adapter to the RecyclerView
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSectionedAdapter);
```

Comment: In the same example can you tell how to apply this cose in a fragment, and how to getdata in sCheeseStrings.

Comment: how do you add a custom layout for the headers?

Comment: What about dynamic data?

Answer (score 13):

If you are looking for a solution that doesn't need to use hardcoded header/row indexes, you can use the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter).

First create a Section class to group your items:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }

    public void addRow(String item) {
        this.list.add(item);
    }

}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data
MySection favoritesSection = new MySection("Favorites", favoritesList);
MySection contactsSection = new MySection("Add Favorites", contactsList);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(favoritesSection);
sectionAdapter.addSection(contactsSection);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

You can also add new rows to your sections without having to recalculate indexes:

```
favoritesSection.addRow("new item");
sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a minimal height for the items list of every section such that if the list is very short, it will still have some height before the next section begins?

Comment: Also, is there a way to display something when there are no content items to display?

Answer (score 6):

In your adapter getItemViewType Layout like this ....

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mCountriesModelList.get(position).isSection) {
            return SECTION_VIEW;
        } else {
            return CONTENT_VIEW;
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/sayanmanna/LetterSectionedRecyclerView

Answer (score 5):

> Let me try to propose a native solution.

You must have a **list of Contacts** with a flag of isFavourite like

```
private class Contacts{
  private String name;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private boolean isFavourite;
}
```

sort that array on the basis of isFavourite and contactName [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name)

pass that list to your ContactRecyclerAdapter. and Use two different layouts for Header and Items [**like this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/3496570)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE(March 2021)**

`ExpandableListView` will not provide the performance and memory benefits provided by RecyclerView. Hence I wrote my own ultra lightweight library that consists of a custom recycler adapter and custom recycler view(only required if grid layout is required) on top on inbuilt `RecyclerViewAdapter` and `RecyclerView` respectively. The adapter exposes some functions similar to how iOS table view works, hence making it super easy to implement sectioned recycler view while sticking to your own code design. Detailed instructions can be found in the project github page linked below. The dependency is available from maven central.

[Sectioned RecyclerView](https://github.com/harikrishnant1991/sectionedrecycleradapter)

```
implementation 'com.github.harikrishnant1991:sectioned-recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

**Original Answer**

Alternative to using any third party library or using custom logic to add header to `RecyclerView`, there is a much simpler solution using Android SDK. You can simply use `ExpandableListView`. You might be thinking that it makes the list collapsible, but there is a very simple thing which you can do to avoid the same. In the adapter class for `ExpandableListView`, in the `getGroupView` method, simply add the following line:

```
(parent as ExpandableListView).expandGroup(groupPosition)
```

The method would look something like this:

```
override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isExpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var view = convertView
    if (convertView == null) {
        val layoutInflater = context
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null)
    }
    /*
     Code to populate your data
     */

    // The following code will expand the group whenever the group view is inflated
    (parent as ExpandableListView).expandGroup(groupPosition)
    return view
}
```

This works simply due to the way how `ExpandableListView` adapter works. Whenever you try to collapse a group header, it calls the `getGroupView` method(so that you can inflate a different view for expanded/collapsed state). But you are expanding the group in that method, hence the view never actually collapses, effectively giving you a sectioned list appearance.

Expect for the one line mentioned above, all other part of the same is exactly as you would do with a normal `ExpandableListView`, hence there is no additional bit of customisation you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my library on Github, can be used to easily create sections:
[RecyclerAdapter & Easy Section](https://github.com/MaximeJallu/RecyclerAdapter-Java#sectiondecorator-recycler-with-linearlayout-or-gridlayout)

```
mRecylerView.setLayoutManager(...);
/*create Adapter*/
RecyclerAdapter<Customer> baseAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter<>(...);
/*create sectioned adapter. the Adapter type can be RecyclerView.Adapter*/
SectionedAdapter<String, RecyclerAdapter> adapter = new SectionedAdapter<>(SectionViewHolder.class, baseAdapter);
/*add your sections*/
sectionAdapter.addSection(0/*position*/, "Title Section 1");
/*attach Adapter to RecyclerView*/
mRecylerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add a `View` in top of your `RecyclerView`'s item layout (e.g. `TextView`) representing section divider and set it's visibility to GONE. Then sort your list and in your adapter do following:

- if position == 0 set VISIBLE + set section name
- if item section == previous item's section set GONE
- else set VISIBLE + section name