# add row to section in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView inside that recyclerView I added two Sections `Favorites`, `All Contacts`. For adding the section I used [SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058)
 now I have rows with section which is hardcoded (the index of rows and section), I want to add rows to `favorite` section by selecting the rows since there's nothing documented about what I want, I don't know where to start or what I have to do ?

If anybody knows how can I add a row from `All Contacts` section (which is default location for rows ) by selecting them.  then please give me some  hints for what I have to do

what I want is something like this :

[image]

add to favorite by pressing the button

any guidance will be so helpful for me , thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add two sections in recyclerview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752980/add-two-sections-in-recyclerview-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) without having to hardcode header/rows indexes.

First create a Section class to group your items:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data
MySection favoritesSection = new MySection("Favorites", favoritesList);
MySection contactsSection = new MySection("Add Favorites", contactsList);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(favoritesSection);
sectionAdapter.addSection(contactsSection);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

You can find an example of how to listen to the button click [here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example1Fragment.java#L91-L95).

You can also add new rows to your sections without having to recalculate indexes, just create a method like this in your Section class:

```
public void addRow(String item) {
    this.list.add(item);
}
```

Then:

```
favoritesSection.addRow("new item");
sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```