# How to set two RecyclerView in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am working on project, i want to make like following recyclerview if click on add icon recycler item add in added recycler[image: RecyclerView list view]

Comment: I have created a sample few days back illustrating how to use nested recycler view. Please have a look at this repository:https://github.com/sagartrehan/NestedRecyclerSample

Comment: Thanks @SagarTrehan , is it helpful for me?

Comment: Yes you can checkout and run the app. It's simple to understand. Let me know if any issue

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there is no need to make two recyclerview. Just create single recyclerview with headers for different sections. You can get hint from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33769698/1690391. Now, when you click on add/remove icon then just change the "itemType" and invalidate your adapter.

Comment: Thank you so much @Manish Kumar , you save  time

Comment: Hey But this is Static type how to use dynamic like on click row

Comment: when i click on add/remove icon then How can i change the "itemType" and invalidate adapter ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. For your question "How can i change the "itemType" and invalidate adapter ?", i prefer you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type. Let me know if you need any more clarification,.