# How to create sticky headers in RecyclerView like the picture attached?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

[image]

I want to implement the title set at the top like the picture above and please be aware that I am using recyclerview like below. Can anyone have any idea?

```
<NestedScrollView>
  <TextView/>
  <RecyclerView/>
  <TextView/>
  <RecyclerView/>
</NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Achieve this, you have to pin your title text view. once the image is scrolled over this, then unpin your title. I suggest you, to use [Sectioned RecyclerView Library](https://github.com/crux-lab/sectioned-recycler-view?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=8099).

With Nested Recycler View & Item Decorator also you can develop like this.