# Sort ArrayList of ArrayList of Floats

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of ArrayList of Floats and I'm looking to sort the array by one of the values of the inner ArrayList.

For example

```
[1.2,2.0,3.5]
[1.3,3.3,5.6]
[5.7,5.3,1.4]
```

I want to sort this by the last value so that the output will be as the following (lowest to highest)

```
[5.7,5.3,1.4]
[1.2,2.0,3.5]
[1.3,3.3,5.6]
```

The values themselves do not change just the order so that the ArrayList goes from lowest to highest based on the 3rd value in the inner ArrayList.

I tried `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(l -> l.get(2)));` as suggested below but I am getting an error: The method comparing(( l) -> {}) is undefined for the type Comparator

Comment: You can pass your custom `Comparator` to the [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

Comment: Sorting list of lists is same as sorting list of any other objects based on property of that object. In your case property is third element in list.

Comment: This is easily done with: `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(l -> l.get(2)));`

Comment: @JornVernee Sorry I'm new to Java and don't understand. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @huddie96 Did you visit duplicate question (you may need to refresh this page to see it at top of your question)?

Comment: @Pshemo I just saw it, the generic bean one seems to be what im looking for but as I said I'm very new and since that deals with strings I believe I have no idea how to convert it.-- I tried though

Comment: @huddie96 Elaborate what exactly? I gave you the code to do what you want, (assuming your list is named `list`).  What don't you understand?

Comment: I took exactly what you said but it generated an error. This works with an ArrayList of floats?

Comment: @huddie96 It works for `List<List<Float>>`, so it would also work for `ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>`.

Comment: Jorn's solution works fine for me. What error did you get exactly?

Comment: Also maybe this answer will help you understand Jorn's answer better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name

Comment: @JornVernee What does the l represent in (l -> l.get(2)..?

Comment: @Pshemo Heres the error: The method comparing((<no type> l) -> {}) is undefined for the type Comparator

Comment: I have a mac and I'm running Java 6

Comment: @huddie96 `l` is the inner list. You need at least Java 8 to use it like that though. Are you by any chance using a raw type for the outer list?

Comment: @JornVernee My outer list is created as so:  public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> Levels = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>(); -- When i switched the project to 1.8 I get many errors

Comment: Okay upgraded and it works. Your answer is so easy (once your running Java 8) you should add it to the original question (since this is a duplicate)