# Find maximum of object field inside an ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have an ArrayList of Nodes. One of the fields of `Node` class is `level`.

I would like to find the level of the node that has the maximum level in the list.

This code gives me an NullPointerException...

```
private int findMaxLevel(ArrayList<Node> nodes)
{
    int level = 0;
    for(Node node : nodes)
    {
        if(node.getLevel() > level)
        {
            level = node.getLevel();
        }
    }
    return level;
}
```

I've tried several implementations of this page : [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name) but I didn't found the solution.

**EDIT :**

Thank you for your suggestions, the level should never be null but I've forgot to add `this.level = level` in the `Node` class constructor....

Comment: are you sure that all of your nodes have a level assigned?

Comment: if (node != null && node.getLevel() > level)

Comment: Show the implementation of `Node` and a minimal complete code that gives the error.

Comment: Are you sure all elements in the list are not null?

Comment: @JohnKane. It appears that `level` is an `int`, and therefore never `null`. The issue is most likely that there are `null` elements in the list.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ. Why in the world would you want to do that? Sorting will turn an O(n) opeation into an O(nlogn)

Comment: I was assuming that it could be an Integer (since no code was shown)

Comment: You are missing the most important information: The JRE exactly tells you in which line of code the NPE occurs! Without that info, we can only guess what is the reason for NPE!

Answer (score 0):

What is the null reference? What does the exceptions says?
Anyway, the only reference in this piece of code is `nodes` so I assume it is it (`getLevel()` returns `int` type which is not nullable)
Maybe you are sending the `ArrayList<Node>` before creating it? Maybe you are using the function like this somewhere:

```
findMaxLevel(null);
```

or

```
ArrayList<Node> nodes = null; // Something like that
findMaxLevel(nodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting apart the NPE...

you can implement **comparable** in the Node class and use a Collections.max to get the max element in the list.

```
int max = Collections.max(a);
System.out.println(max);
```

but why overriding comparable:?

**Collections.max()** is implemented as:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    Iterator<? extends T> i = coll.iterator();
    T candidate = i.next();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        T next = i.next();
        if (next.compareTo(candidate) > 0)
            candidate = next;
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

so compareTo will be called to find the [max element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator))

Comment: Nope. Overriding `equals` does not define an order. You want to implement `Comparable` to make `Collections.max()` work!

Answer (score 0):

You might use `stream` api for that. I assume that your node class has an `int` field `level`

```
 class Node {
            private int level;
            public int getLevel() {
                return  level;
            }
            public void setLevel(int level) {
                this.level = level;
            }
 }
```

Now we need to find out maxim level in a `List` with `Nodes`:

```
Optional<Integer> maxLevel = nodes.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(Node::getLevel).max(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder());
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping things simple with this one-liner:

```
    Node max = nodes.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .max((Node node, Node t1) -> t1.level < node.level ? 1 : -1)
                    .get();
```

Make sure to check and see if the list is empty first or use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), otherwise you might get a NoSuchElementException.