# OpenCV Java removing objects from scene

Tags: java, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I have successfully detected bounding boxes, now I want to remove everything else in the image and just remain with the content of the bounding boxes to improve on tesseract accuracy, below is an image representation of what I have done and need (I want the binary images to only contain the letters, all the other objects to be removed):

[image: I want the binary images to only contain the letters, all the other objects to be removed]

and my code:

```
 public static ProcessedFrame preProcessImage(Mat image){
    originalFrame = image.clone();
    roiColor = image.clone();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0);
    originalFrameGrayScale = image.clone();
    Mat morph = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(9, 9));
    Imgproc.morphologyEx(image, image, Imgproc.MORPH_TOPHAT, morph);
    Imgproc.Sobel(image, image, -1, 2, 0);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, image, new Size(5,5), 3,3);
    Imgproc.morphologyEx(image, image, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, morph);
    Imgproc.threshold(image, image, 200, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    Vector<Rect> rectangles = detectionContour(image);
    Mat roi = originalFrameGrayScale.clone();
    if(!rectangles.isEmpty()){
    roi = originalFrameGrayScale.submat(rectangles.get(0));
    roiBlack = roi.clone();
    roiColor = roiColor.submat(rectangles.get(0));
      Imgproc.rectangle(originalFrame, rectangles.get(0).br(), rectangles.get(0).tl(), new Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
    }
   Imgproc.medianBlur(roi, roi, 3); 
   Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(roi, roi, 225, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 3);
   Imgproc.medianBlur(roi, roi, 3);
   Imgproc.medianBlur(roi, roi, 3); 
   Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(roi, roi, 225, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 3);
   Imgproc.medianBlur(roi, roi, 3);
   roiBinarize = roi.clone();
   Mat erode = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(3, 3));
   Mat dilate = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT,new Size(3, 3));
   Imgproc.morphologyEx(roi, roi, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, dilate);
   Imgproc.morphologyEx(roi, roi, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, erode);
   Vector<Rect> letters = detectionPlateCharacterContour(roi);
   doTesseractOCR(letters, roiBinarize);
    return  new ProcessedFrame(originalFrame, roiColor, roiBinarize, roi);

}






private static void doTesseractOCR(Vector<Rect> letters, Mat plate){
    Tesseract instance = new Tesseract(); //
    instance.setLanguage(LANGUAGE);
    String resultPlate = "AAA0000";
    for(int i= 0; i < letters.size(); i++){

     BufferedImage letter = OpenCvUtils.Mat2bufferedImage(plate.submat(letters.get(i)));
        try {
        String result = instance.doOCR(letter);
        String character = result.replace("\n", "");
        resultPlate = new StringBuilder(resultPlate).replace(i ,i+1, character).toString();
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Tesseract output: "+resultPlate);
    }

     try {
        String result = instance.doOCR(OpenCvUtils.Mat2bufferedImage(roiBinarize));
        System.out.println("Tesseract output2: "+result.replace("\n", ""));
         } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}





 private static Vector<Rect> detectionPlateCharacterContour(Mat roi) {
    Mat contHierarchy = new Mat();
    Mat imageMat = roi.clone();
    Rect rect = null;
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(imageMat, contours, contHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Vector<Rect> rect_array = new Vector<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
        double ratio = 0;

               if(rect.height > rect.width){
            ratio = rect.height/rect.width;

            }else{
                ratio = rect.width/rect.height;

            }
         Logger.printMessage("Ratio of letter: "+ratio);
      double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));
         if (contourarea >= 160 && contourarea <= 1000 && ( ratio >= 1 && ratio <= 2)) {
         Imgproc.rectangle(roiColor, rect.br(), rect.tl(), new Scalar(10,50,255));
           rect_array.add(rect);
         }
    }


    contHierarchy.release();
    return rect_array;
}




 private static Vector<Rect> detectionContour(Mat outmat) {
    Mat contHierarchy = new Mat();
    Mat imageMat = outmat.clone();

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();

    Imgproc.findContours(imageMat, contours, contHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    Vector<Rect> rect_array = new Vector<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));

        Mat contour = contours.get(i);
        double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);

            double ratio = 0;
            int radius = 0;
            if(rect.height > rect.width){
            ratio = rect.height/rect.width;
            radius = rect.height/2;
            }else{
                ratio = rect.width/rect.height;
                radius = rect.width/2;
            }
        if (contourarea >= 2000 && contourarea <= 10000 && ( ratio == 1 || ratio == 2)) {   
            Logger.printMessage("Rectangle ratio: "+ratio);
            MatOfPoint2f mat2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
            contours.get(i).convertTo(mat2f, CvType.CV_32FC2);
            RotatedRect rotatedRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect( mat2f );
            double rotationAngle = rotatedRect.angle;
            if(rotatedRect.angle > 0)
                rotationAngle = 90 - rotatedRect.angle;
            else
               rotationAngle = rotatedRect.angle; 
            Logger.printMessage("Rotation is: "+(rotationAngle));
            rect = enlargeROI(originalFrame, rect, 10);
            rect_array.add(rect);
        }
    }


    contHierarchy.release();
    return rect_array;
}





private Vector<Rect> detectionContours(Mat outmat) {
    Mat contHierarchy = new Mat();
    Mat imageMat = outmat.clone();
    Rect contourRect = null;
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(imageMat, contours, contHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Vector<Rect> rect_array = new Vector<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Mat contour = contours.get(i);
        double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
        if (contourarea > minBlob && contourarea < maxBlob) {
            contourRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
            rect_array.add(contourRect);
        }
    }


    contHierarchy.release();
    return rect_array;
}
```

When i run this code printing out the centroid of each rectangle i find that
 2 x: 18.0 y: 111.0
2 x: 42.0 y:109.0
7 x: 65.0 y: 108.0
0x:89.0 y: 108.0
A x: 29.0 y: 61.0
C x: 52.0 y: 58.0
P x: 77.0 y: 58.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCv enhancing image for OCR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958962/opencv-enhancing-image-for-ocr) -- please, instead of posting another question about what's apparently the same issue, enhance the original question appropriately.

Comment: I deleted the post, it was wrongly asked.

Comment: OK :) | What do you want to replace the parts of the image you "remove" with? (I assume we're talking about some further steps to do with the image in the bottom-right corner of the attached image.) Since you feed tesseract a vector of bounding boxes specifying individual detected letters, I assume this is just some cosmetic requirement for display?

Comment: No it's not for cosmetic requirement, the problem with process the characters one by one is i cannot their position hence in the end i get a tangled string of there is a way of knowing which bounding box js which i could start with the top line from left to right the the second but i can't tell

Comment: Are you sure there's no predictable order to the results you get? You will definitely benefit from already having the symbols segmented. Can you post an example of your results? Are all the licence plates guaranteed to have two lines? You could probably partition the symbols into two groups based on y coordinate and then sort by x in each group. | To get rid of the other stuff, I'd just make a new image of same size filled with white, and then copy over each symbol ROI from the source.

Comment: Am reading about ordering the contour based on xy but have no idea on how to go about it, and yesall my plates will be 2 lines

Comment: Output looks like 2276ACP but in other images it gets even worse

Comment: OK, can you add to your question a list of coordinates (x,y,width,height) of the 7 bounding boxes for the symbols in the sample image, as well this result you just mentioned? Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43959461/edit) feature. I'll have a look at it when I wake up, if someone doesn't beat me to it ;) | Feel free to add some details about those cases where it gets even worse.

Comment: @DanMašek any luck?

Comment: There you go. Should be fairly simple to turn than into code -- really just some modifications to your `doTesseractOCR` method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to do some preprocessing on your letter bounding boxes, and it would probably make sense to do it before feeding them to Tesseract, although it's not strictly necessary. Let's begin by annotating our sample image with contour indices, and tabulating their attributes.

[image: Annotated LP]

```
contour | bbox centroid | recognised
index   |   x   |   y   | symbol
--------+-------+-------+-----------
0       |  18.0 | 111.0 |   2
1       |  42.0 | 109.0 |   2
2       |  65.0 | 108.0 |   7
3       |  89.0 | 108.0 |   0
4       |  29.0 |  61.0 |   A
5       |  52.0 |  58.0 |   C
6       |  77.0 |  58.0 |   P
```

When a person reads this license plate, they start with the top-most row of symbols, and read the symbols from left to right. After they reach the right-most symbol, they move to the next lower row, and again go from left to right. Therefore, we should organize our symbols (or the bounding boxes that represent them) in a structure that will let us do this easily.

We can use `Vector<Rect>` to represent each row of symbols. Since there are always two rows of symbols, we will need two instances of this vector -- let's refer to them as *row0* and *row1*.

---

The first task is to categorize the bounding boxes of symbols into two groups, and based on this add them to the appropriate row vector. A simple approach to this may be something like this:

- Calculate mean value of the `y` coordinate of symbol centroids. In our example, it's approximately `mean_y=87.5`.
- For each detected symbol:

  - If `y` coordinate of symbol centroid is less than `mean_y`, add the symbol to *row0*
  - Otherwise add the symbol to *row1*

When we perform this algorithm on our sample set of symbols, we see that

```
     | contained
row  | symbol ids
-----+--------------
row0 |  4, 5, 6
row1 |  0, 1, 2, 3
```

In case this simple approach turns out to be insufficient, you can try some more advanced [means of clustering](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html).

---

The second task is to sort each row so the symbols go left to right:

- For each row:

  - Sort row elements in ascending order by the `x` coordinate of their centroid

My Java is quite rusty, but you could probably do this using a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You can refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814112/3962537) for more details on how to sort collections in Java.

In our sample, the elements within each row are already in order, so there's nothing to do...

```
     | contained
row  | symbol ids
-----+--------------
row0 |  4, 5, 6
row1 |  0, 1, 2, 3
```

---

Now we can

- For each row:

  - For each symbol in row

    - Process with Tesseract
    - Handle the result as required (e.g. print)

In our sample, we'd get

```
ACP
2270
```