# How to call a method on an ArrayList, which is in an other class?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, console

I'm in the process of creating a Airport registration model. The program is interactive through the terminal (cmd/IDE) and able to add different object types to ArrayLists. I would like to list all the created object with their corresponding fields.

I created a method for listing all the generated AirFields through the terminal, but for Flights, Passengers, Crews, I do not know how to do that. Thanks for helping! Learning to become a Junior Java Dev. Thanks.

```
private static List<AirField> airfields = new ArrayList<>();
static int startingIndexToOne = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                  //writing in/reading from the console
    boolean looperMain = true;

    while (looperMain) {

        System.out.println("Create a new...: a - AIRFIELD, f - FLIGHT, p - PASSENGER, c - CREW MEMBER");
        System.out.println("Other input commands: exit - EXIT PROGRAM");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        String line = reader.readLine();


        switch (line) {
            case "exit":
                looperMain = false;
                break;

            case "a":
                AirField airfield = new AirField();
                System.out.println("An AIRFIELD has been instantiated!");
                System.out.print("Assign a NAME to the AIRFIELD: ");
                airfield.setName(reader.readLine());

                airfields.add(airfield);
                System.out.println("The " + (airfields.indexOf(airfield) + startingIndexToOne) + ".AIRFIELD's name has been set as [" + airfield.getName() + "].");
                System.out.println();

                getListAirFields();
                airfield.getListFlights();
                break;

            case "f":
                Flight flight = new Flight();
                System.out.println("The FLIGHT has been instantiated.");
                System.out.println("Assign a CODE to the FLIGHT: ");
                flight.setCode(reader.readLine());


                System.out.println("The FLIGHT's code has been set as [" + flight.getCode() + "].");
                System.out.println();


                break;

            case "p":
                Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
                System.out.println("A passenger has been instantiated.");
                System.out.print("Assign a NAME to the PASSENGER: ");

                passenger.setName(reader.readLine());
                System.out.print("\nThe PASSENGER's name has been set as [" + passenger.getName() + "].");

                System.out.print("\nAssign " + passenger.getName() + "'s checked bags value(in Kg): ");

                int checkedBagsInKg = reader.read();
                passenger.setCheckedBagsInKg(checkedBagsInKg);
                System.out.println(passenger.getName() + "'s checked bags has been set as [" + passenger.getCheckedBagsInKg() + " kg].");

                break;

            case "c":
                Crew crewMember = new Crew();
                System.out.println("A CREW MEMBER has been instantiated.");
                System.out.print("Assign the NAME of the CREW MEMBER: ");
                crewMember.setName(reader.readLine());

                System.out.print("The CREW MEMBER's name has been set as [" + crewMember.getName() + "].");

                System.out.print("Assign " + crewMember.getName() + "'s JOB type: ");
                crewMember.setCrewJob(reader.readLine());
                System.out.println(crewMember.getName() + "'s JOB type has been set as [" + crewMember.getCrewJob() + "]");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Error: Incorrect input.");
                break;
        }
    }

}

private static void getListAirFields () { //reading airfield one by one from the ArrayList<AirField> airfields.

    System.out.println("Created airfields: ");
    System.out.println();

    for (AirField airfield : airfields) {
        System.out.println("#" + (airfields.indexOf(airfield) + startingIndexToOne) + " airfield: " + "Name - " + airfield.getName());
    }
}
```

}

public class AirField implements Iterable {

```
public static List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<>();
String name;

public List<Flight> getFlights() {
    return flights;
}

public void setFlights(List<Flight> flights) {
    this.flights = flights;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public Iterator<Flight> iterator() {
    return flights.iterator();
}

public void getListFlights() {

    System.out.println("Created flights: ");

    for (Flight flight : flights) {
        System.out.println(flight.getCode());
    }
}
```

public class Flight implements Iterable {

```
private String code;
private static List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Person> getPeople() {
    return people;
}

public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
    this.people = people;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

@Override
public Iterator<Person> iterator() {
    return people.iterator();
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you create a `List<Flight>`, `List<Passenger>` and `List<Crew>`? What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: Those were created in different classes.

Comment: Can you show them(a minimal example)? You need to add the Flight, Crew, Passenger to the array list in those classes

Comment: can you show us the code where those other Lists are created?

Comment: Added to post a few of those classes.

Comment: You have getter method for your list, you can just do `airfield.getFlights()`

Comment: You may also want add to your is there a pattern I can use..

Comment: In order to use {airfield.getFlights()} on an airfield, the flights have to be registrated to the airfield. How to do that? With looping?

Comment: If by airfield you mean terminal, you should have terminal designation assigned to each flight, you then get what you need using sort or filter with Comparator https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814112/3254405