# How can i sorted arraylist from 2 different arraylist? like two arraylist, gender and student. How to view the student details in genderwise

Tags: java, android

```
stringArrayList.add(gender_type);
stdentlists.add(new Stdentlists(id,gender_type,std_name,std_age,std_class));


Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>(stringArrayList);
ArrayList<String> afterRemovingduplicate = new ArrayList<String>(stringSet);
```

Comment: Show your Student class

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-objects-using-a-custom-sorting-order

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separate arraylist,Create one model which has fields like gender,student... etc. And the try to sort that single arraylist.