# Sorting List<> in Java

Tags: java, string, list, sorting

I have a `List<Person>`. Person's attributes are String name, String secondName, int phoneNum.

How can I sort this List by the String property secondName?

I've tried moving into another `List<String>` the data from the previous list moving secondName to the first position, then applying Collection.sort and creating other `List<Person>` with the data of the List sorted but its too complicated.

Comment: [Sorting an ArrayList of objects using a custom sorting order](//stackoverflow.com/q/1814095)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an ArrayList of objects using a custom sorting order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-objects-using-a-custom-sorting-order)

Comment: Yes it does, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 introduced a sort method in the List interface which can use a comparator.

If you have a getter for secondName you can do this:

```
 myList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getSecondName));
```

If you don't have a getter use this one:

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparing((person)->(person.secondName)));
```

for more ways and answers:
[link](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/sort-list-of-objects-by-field-java)

Comment: The OP didn't mention any getters.

Comment: @WJS true. thanks for saying

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume here is your Pojo Class Person.

```
class Person{
String name;
String secondName;
//Getter and setters
}
```

Then sort the list by java collection API itself.

```
java.util.Collections.sort(personList, new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            return o1.getSecondName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getSecondName());
        }
        });
```